# Why can't change the input data if the variable declaration is inside of a for loop in bash

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

So im trying to make an infinity loop, that creates libraries.

but the file variable take input only once.

code:

```
for (( ; ; ))
do
    file=${1?Error: no input}
    mkdir "$file"
    sleep 1
done
```

Comment: What is your expected behavior including the interaction with a user?

Comment: i expected it will ask for an other input, but it wont, so it just keep on trying making the directory with the same data, so i get the "cannot create directory : File exists" error

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in that loop that asks for input. `$1` is provided once by the user as they run the script (before the loop even starts). The standard way to request input in a shell script is with the `read` command. Something like this:

```
while read -p "Enter a directory to create: " file; do
    mkdir "$file"
done
```

This loop will terminate when it receives an end-of-file, which means the user must press Control-D to exit it. If you want to exit if the user just presses return without entering anything, you could do this:

```
while read -p "Enter a directory to create: " file; do
    if [ -z "$file" ]; then
        echo "Error: no input" >&2
        break    # This exits the while loop
    fi
    mkdir "$file"
done
```

Comment: Of course, not using a script at all is a much superior approach. If you factor out the `read` you only need `mkdir -p` and then you can use your shell's tab completion, history, and other file name manipulation features to pass in as many arguments as you like easily.